# How can I get my Spring Security SecurityConfig to register?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an app running the Jersey Spring dispatcher, and I want to integrate with Spring Security. I can get it to work with the namespace configuration -- i.e. including the filter in web.xml and using `<http>` and `<authentication-manager>` bean definitions. Note that I am not using Spring MVC, but the Jersey Spring dispatcher instead.

I want to use Java config with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.

However, when I cut-and-paste those classes from the tutorials, I can access Jersey resources & the authentication doesn't kick in. I can access all my resources without a challenge. From all I've read, it sounds like WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is creating the filter and the security chain, but I don't understand how those are supposed to hook into the web application.

Most of the threads I've seen degenerate into discussions of classes that I have no idea of what they are or where they go.

I can get the namespace config to work, so what am I missing to get the Initializer to register?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

...

and probably component-scan somewhere in your spring configuration, so it know which packages to scan while looking for beans.

If everything is against you - turn on spring logs, add:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

to your log4j.properties

Comment: I tried declaring my SecurityConfig explicitly as a bean in applicationContext, but that didn't do the trick. I'll give component-scan a try, and then look at logs like you suggest.